# How can current offset be so high and log end offset be too low in Kafka resulting in too high negative Kafka lag?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have been using Kafka and the problem we are facing is too high negative Kafka. How can current offset be 4933973245 and log end offset be only 1924 in Kafka which resulting in negative Kafka lag?

Probably due to this some messages are not being even consumed in Java consumer.

Can this be a configuration issue? Any insights?

We are using Spring Kafka.

Comment: May be you confused different topics/partitions?

Comment: @G.Domozhirov - It's same topic only with such high negative Kafka lag.

Comment: Please show how you calculate lag... It's already a JMX metric, so are you doing it manually?